# How can I get count of total submission in Forminator Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, customization

I have tried to get all quizzes submission count but there is get only first-page quizzes count (http://prntscr.com/phcby8). I need to get all the quizzes submission count.

I have tried this way :

```
function get_all_quiz_form_id() {

    $forms = Forminator_API::get_quizzes();
    $form_ids = array();
    foreach ( $forms as $form ) {
        $form_ids[] = $form->id;
    }

    return $form_ids;
}

$get_count = get_all_quiz_form_id();
$count = 0;
foreach ( $get_count as $key => $FORM_ID ) {
    $entries = Forminator_API::get_entries( intval( $FORM_ID ) );
    $count+= count( $entries );
}

echo $count;
```

I want to get a count of all 64 quizzes submission.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed this issue. I have to get count using custom queries and Forminator_API is take a time to get data when lots of data in the database so Custom query is best for the count.

```
function get_all_submission_count() {
    ob_start();
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'frmt_form_entry';
    $count_query = "select count(*) from $table_name";
    $count = $wpdb->get_var($count_query);
    return $count;
}
```

Thanks :)